# Double check - does it ever make sense to have internal viewmodel class?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, binding

I believe we cannot bind to internal viewmodel.

Therefore I think all binding related implementations of IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged should be always public in order to work with XAML.

Is that correct?

**UPDATE:** this isn't such an easy question because there are various possible weird cases, like nested viewmodel classes, or explicit interface implementations or something else that I am not aware of which could possibly lead to different answers. As we already can see WPF and SL4.0 treat internal viewmodels differently for some reason.

Comment: `I think all binding related implementations... should be always public` -- Is that a problem?

Comment: I just seek definite knowledge. I have no problems with having public viewmodels. I have problems not knowing exact details of why and what is possible or not. Lets say its a tricky interview question (its not however). Can you explain why behaviour is different in WPF and SL for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some checking, based on this code:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <sa1:TestValueConverter x:Key="TestValueConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource TestValueConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class TestValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "-" + value.ToString() + "-";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, results **are different** for WPF and Silverlight.

And answers are:

In Silverlight:

1. "I believe we cannot bind to internal viewmodel" - yes we **cannot**
   bind to internal class, nor can we bind to internal or private
   properties, gives binding error.
2. "implementations of IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter" - yes also should be public
3. "INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged" - these interfaces are implemented by classes of ViewModel and some collection that will be bound, so these classes should be public as we already know. And methods and events that implement interfaces cannot be private or internal obviously.

In WPF:

1. "I believe we cannot bind to internal viewmodel" - we **can** bind to internal class, but we cannot bind to internal or private properties.
2. "implementations of IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter" - **can** be internal
3. "INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged" - see previous points.

Comment: its interesting.. I wonder why SL gives an error when we bind to internal type and WPF does not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind to internal properties, but it does not matter how accessible the source object (e.g. the `DataContext`) is as long as the properties are public.

If it makes sense to restrict the access is another issue depending on the function of your classes and your assembly. I am not an expert on this but if the assembly is not going to be used by another one then you probably do not need to worry about its outer interface which can be controlled using `internal`.

Comment: this doesn't appear to be true

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: What part, and what makes you think so? Based on your ipdate, do you mean that SL does not allow such bindings?

Comment: well "but it does not matter how accessible the source object" - this part is not true for SL. Thats also the only part of your answer which is relevant to my question. You imply that I am worried, but am not really worried, I am just asking a question.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: If you have no reason to control the interface of your components why would you even ask about making things internal? Also don't tag questions with WPF or make it clear in the question if you want only silverlight answers...

Comment: I dont only need Silverlight answers, thats the point. I needed both types of answers. I am mostly Silverlight currently, and for example didn't know that in WPF its different. So I was surprised with your reply initially too, turns out its partly correct in WPF, but when applied to both worlds it becomes incorrect. I hope I am clear here. As you can see Deafsheep explores both worlds in his answer for example.

Comment: Those things are just a matter of testing, what's the point of asking about it? As i see it the much more important part is whether a viewmodel *should* be made internal (given that the bindings would still work)

Comment: well I don't think it Should be made internal because for example I got different assemblies for xaml and viewmodels. The question is important to me, and it requires exhaustive testing, and even after I can be done with 2 hours of testing I still cannot be sure I tested all possible cases, so I believe asking is better because people who know some tricky spots can highlight them to me and save from mistake (its actually related to obfuscating assemblies in the end).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the two environments (Silverlight and WPF) behave differently is because of the silverlight reflection limitations.

In silverlight you can not use [reflection on internal or private members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc%28VS.95%29.aspx).

So if the viewmodel is declared as internal, silverlight will not be able to use it for databinding.