# viewmodel have to be public. How should I deal with that?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Pretty much it summarizes my problem here:
[Double check - does it ever make sense to have internal viewmodel class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576102/double-check-does-it-ever-make-sense-to-have-internal-viewmodel-class)

I have controls.DLL and I'd like to keep this custom control bindings and viewmodel's internal. However, this doesn't seem to be possible.

How do you get around that? The only way I see it - don't use bindings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a view model for a custom control? I assume you're assigning the view model object to the DataContext property, but this is almost always a mistake: the DataContext should be available to consumers to use and abuse as they please. Stated another way, what happens if a consumer of your custom control explicitly sets the DataContext? It sounds like your control will stop working and throw a bunch of xaml binding errors.

A custom control is inherently lookless. There is no model or view model, just a view. That view is the .cs file. You supply a default look via your themes/generic.xaml file, but consumers should be able to supply their own template. If you're tying them to a view model, they also need to know how to create a view model instance and all of its dependencies. You've just created highly coupled code. DI containers can loosen the coupling, but that just downgrades the relationship between classes from "coupled" to "related". I say, why do consumers even need to know that information?

A better approach is to provide all of the properties for your control as dependency properties. Then your generic.xaml can provide a control template that uses the more efficient TemplateBinding to bind properties/objects to your control. If you need to populate these dependency properties from a business object, expose another dependency property of type IBusinessObject and set the derived values in that object's PropertyMetaData changed handler. If your IBusinessObject type contains a property which is yet another class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you should probably (1) rethink your object graph or (2) create a Bnding object in code using the subclass.

I think following all of the above advice will eliminate the problem about which you're concerned plus the other problems as well. Leave the view models to the UserControls. And yes, this is why custom controls are a MASSIVE headache. Doing them right is fairly involved.

Comment: Live and learn. I'm just starting with controls. I turned to VM because I needed binding and therefore I had to set DataContext. Now it's a-ha! moment when I realize that Dependency property to TemplateBinding is like regular property via DataContext to binding. Am I right? I have fairly sophisticated control which mine as well could be UserControl. But I thought Control should be more efficient? Users of controls is us, so I'm not really concerned here. But at the same time I want to do it right. Now I get it though. I'm sure I will post more questions :)

Comment: You would use control if you want to allow or provide completely different looks to the control. For example, a clock control could provide a basic digital interface, but consumers of the control could retemplate it to have an analog interface (or even a binary interface). If you don't have this need or desire, don use a custom control.

Comment: Regarding TemplateBinding, you're on the right track. It's equivalent to Binding where Source is set to "RelativeSource TemplatedParent". Because of this assumption, TemplateBinding provides fewer features than Binding but is more efficient as a result.

Comment: Wouldn't custom control perform better then UserControl?

Comment: You know, I just can't find any performance information.  My guess is that UserControl is actually more performant because it doesn't have to deal with templating.  From the documentation on UserControl: "Two other primary reasons for creating a control that inherits from UserControl are 1) to separate functionality into smaller, manageable pieces of logic that can be created independently from an application and other controls; 2) to group related controls that can be used more than once in an application."  It just doesn't say anything about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try protected internal. I suppose this should work. Although I don't think its good idea to have the ViewModel not public at all, cause one of the purposes of it is to be able to define several Views against the same ViewModel, which may come from different assemblies.

Comment: In this case MVVM just easier to program, Internal doesn't work. Both property and class have to be public